# Не получается получить значение из первого RichEdit из окна Lync

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pywinauto

Этим кодом я получаю не первый попавшийся элемент, а последний:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application().connect(class_name='CommunicatorMainWindowClass')
window = app.window(class_name='CommunicatorMainWindowClass')

# window.print_control_identifiers()
window.NetUINativeHWNDHost.NetUIHWND.print_control_identifiers()

print()
rich_edit = window.NetUINativeHWNDHost.NetUIHWND.NetUICtrlNotifySink.RICHEDIT60W
print(rich_edit.WindowText())
```

Печатается такой список элементов:

```
Control Identifiers:

NetUIHWND - ''    (L162, T378, R562, B957)
['', '1', 'NetUIHWND', '0']
child_window(class_name="NetUIHWND")
   | 
   | NetUICtrlNotifySink - ''    (L186, T408, R537, B425)
   | ['2', 'NetUICtrlNotifySink1', 'NetUICtrlNotifySink', 'NetUICtrlNotifySink0']
   | child_window(class_name="NetUICtrlNotifySink")
   |    | 
   |    | RICHEDIT60W - '///'    (L186, T408, R537, B425)
   |    | ['RICHEDIT60W0', '///RICHEDIT60W', 'RICHEDIT60W1', '///', 'RICHEDIT60W']
   |    | child_window(title="///", class_name="RICHEDIT60W")
   | 
   | RICHEDIT60W - '///'    (L186, T408, R537, B425)
   | ['RICHEDIT60W0', '///RICHEDIT60W', 'RICHEDIT60W1', '///', 'RICHEDIT60W']
   | child_window(title="///", class_name="RICHEDIT60W")
   | 
   | NetUICtrlNotifySink - ''    (L184, T548, R515, B562)
   | ['3', 'NetUICtrlNotifySink2']
   | child_window(class_name="NetUICtrlNotifySink")
   |    | 
   |    | RICHEDIT60W - 'qwerty'    (L184, T548, R515, B562)
   |    | ['RICHEDIT60W2', 'qwerty', 'qwertyRICHEDIT60W']
   |    | child_window(title="qwerty", class_name="RICHEDIT60W")
   | 
   | RICHEDIT60W - 'qwerty'    (L184, T548, R515, B562)
   | ['RICHEDIT60W2', 'qwerty', 'qwertyRICHEDIT60W']
   | child_window(title="qwerty", class_name="RICHEDIT60W")
   | 
   | NetUICtrlNotifySink - ''    (L162, T378, R162, B378)
   | ['4', 'NetUICtrlNotifySink3']
   | child_window(class_name="NetUICtrlNotifySink")

qwerty
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно по списку элементов, первым должен был быть "///", а не "qwerty"
В чем проблема? Как получить элемент с "///"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось сделать таким образом:

```
import pywinauto
window = pywinauto.findwindows.find_element(title_re='Microsoft Lync.*')
child = window.children()[3]
print(child.rich_text)  #  ///
```